# check if datetime exists in a string powershell

Tags: powershell

Im a complete powershell beginner. I have to read a log file and check if the last entry is of current time stamp.

I have fetched last line using Get-Content;

```
PS> Write-Host $lastLine
new levels are  10/12/2016 4:23:34 PM
PS> $x =Get-Date
PS> Write-Host $x
10/12/2016 4:23:34 PM
```

I've tried using -match as well as -contains
 while regex,casting param to string etc., but to no avail

```
1.PS C:\Users\xxx> $y = $lastLine -Match [regex]::escape($x)
2.PS C:\Users\xxx> $y=$lastLine -contains $x
```

and few other, P.N: checked $y value after each of above case.
$y is returning false., can anyone guide me to a reference/solution. I'm missing something here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a **formatted date string** stored in the variable `$formattedDate` you can test if the line ends with a space followed by that date string using...

```
$lastLine -like "* $formattedDate";
```

Remember that the `Get-Date` cmdlet returns a `DateTime` value, not a `string`.  When you use operators such as `-like` or `-match` to search for a date in a specific format, you'll want to ensure that your date variable gets formatted the way you expect it to.  That is, don't rely on the default, culture-specific date formatting but rather specify exactly what you need:

```
$date = Get-Date;
$formattedDate = $date.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt');
if ($lastLine -like "* $formattedDate")
{
    # ...
}
```

You can combine the first two lines into one using the `-Format` parameter:

```
$formattedDate = Get-Date -Format 'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt';
```